# Can I determine the difference of declaring (and not declaring) a file to use lexical-binding?

Tags: lexical-binding

I have been trying to understand what difference it makes if you set the file variable `lexical-binding` to `t` for a particular source file.

As mentioned in [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding) that in order to use lexical-bindings in your source files, you specifically have to opt for it by setting the local file variable.

However, with all that I tried, I could not find any difference in the behavior of the source code within the file and being able to access variables declared in the file from outside and vice-versa.

Is there a way I can see the difference myself for how using `;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-` in the first line of my source files enables lexical-binding instead of using dynamic-binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a trivial example:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun foo ()
  x)

(let ((x 'y))
  (foo))
```

Save that file and use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-file` to load it, and you will get an error:

```
let: Symbol’s value as variable is void: x
```

On account of lexical variable `x` not being visible within function `foo`.

Under dynamic binding, `foo` would see the value `y`.

> ... being able to access variables declared in the file ...

Note that if the variables are *declared* with `defvar` or `defcustom` or similar, then they are dynamically bound.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.